# Is getting wolves early still viable?

Tags: league-of-legends

I used to play Jungle Trundle all the time, and when they changed him to fit into the Freljord story line, I had no problems adapting because riot basically buffed him.  But the recent change to the jungle and how the creeps spawn is making me weary of using the troll with a club, or jungling at all for that matter.

My old Jungle plan was buy the Machete and 3 pots, do Wolves, smite blue, do Wraiths, do golems, smite red, base to buy things then continue ganking as needed. (Trundle's passive is awesome, allowing him to sustain through all that jungling in one go)

However, I'm unsure as to what route to take now.
Do I start blue, then go wolves then continue as normal?
Do I wait the longer time for wolves, grab them then blue and continue like nothing happened?
Do I hit blue and just skip wolves and continue on?
I'd like to know the advantages and disadvantages of the three above scenarios, mainly for Trundle, but points on how the affect other main junglers would be helpful too.
(For example, same three questions but replace blue with red, wolves with wraiths, and Trundle with Shyvana)

Comment: I always do:blue(smite) -> wolfs -> wraiths -> golems -> red(smite) -> wraiths(they should have re spawend by then) this will make you lv 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No its not still viable.

With the larger camps(ancient golem/elder lizard) spawning at 1:55 and the smaller camps(wraiths,golems,wolves,wight) spawning at 2:05, you can't expect much more from your team than helping with the big camps.

Unfortunately, this change requires that junglers alter their clear path slightly to cope, but it also means camps are more plentiful in the beginning because your team won't be taking golems/wraiths/wolves (as Sconibulus mentioned, the reason for the change was to prevent this). Respawn timers for the small camps(wraiths/wolves/golems) have been reduced by 10 seconds(60 down to 50) so they will be up more frequently, and [Smite](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Smite) cooldown was reduced to 40 seconds(from 70), so keep this in mind as you're pathing through the jungle.

Of course these paths may not apply for everyone here's my attempt at a general guide:

### Mana/Ancient Golem Start

- Ancient Golem
- Wolves (then continue on how your normally would)
- Elder Lizard (look for gank possibilities)
- Wraiths
- Golems or wolves or Wight(if you did gank mid after red clear wolves first as they're closer and should be up) etc.. perhaps a side bush gank if you went golems

### Red/Elder Lizard Start

- Elder Lizard (if you're champ has a good lvl 2 gank look for it here)
- Wraiths (always be looking for gank possibilities)
- Ancient Golem
- Wolves (Get some ganks in already)
- Wight
- Wraiths should be up again etc continue on as usual

### Blue/Red Gank courtesy of Schism

- Ancient Golem
- Elder Lizard (hit 3)
- Gank
- Continue on clearing the small camps

### 2v1 Lane (you chose)

- Start similar to either 1 or 2
- Let the solo lane facing 2 opponents take some small camps as he needs to wait for lane to push.
- Join the 2v1 lane to make it a 3v1 and either gank(if they're solo lane is dumb enough to try to defend) or push the tower down quickly.

### 2v1 Lane (they chose)

- Start similar to either 1 or 2
- Let the solo lane facing 2 opponents take some small camps as he needs to wait for lane to push.
- Join the 2v1 lane to make it a 2v2 lane until your 2v1 lane can take a tower

See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/119280/18146) as to why you would 2v1 or why you'd want to prevent a 2v1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure timers did change. Wolves and Golems (and maybe Wraiths) spawn more frequently than they used to.

Comment: @StrixVaria You are definitely correct, I must have missed this in the patch notes, fixed thanks

Comment: An additional route you should include is Blue -> Red -> Level 3 Gank.